# Defualt value in Model property for MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Having this code in a .cshtml file in MVC 4 application:

```
<div class="td">
   <div class="td-l">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MeetingHeader.Company, "Company:")
   </div>
   <div class="td-r">
     <label id="lblCompanyValue">@Model.MeetingHeader.Company.Name</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I insert a default value ("Company not present") when @Model.MeetingHeader.Company is null?

Answer (score 1):

you will have to change your model

```
public class Company 
{
   private sring _name;
   
   public string Name {

       get { 
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name) return _name;
               return "Company not present";
           }
       set { 
             _name=value; 
            }
      }
   ......
}
```